# shipping and handling fee calculation

Tags: javascript

Here is the question:
Many companies normally charge a shipping and handling fee for purchases. Create a Web page that allows a user to enter a purchase price into a text box - include a JavaScript function that calculates shipping and handling. Add functionality to the script that adds a minimum shipping and handling fee of $1.50 for any purchase that is less than or equal to $25.00. For any orders over $25.00, add 10% to the total purchase price for shipping and handling, but do not include the $1.50 minimum shipping and handling fee. After you determine the total cost of the order (purchase plus shipping and handling), display it in an alert dialog box.

I am beginner at JavaScript and struggling to get my code to work. It does display an alert box with the value entered by the user but doesn't add anything. Although, I don't know why the formula doesn't work. Please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Calculating Shipping & Handling</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

/* <![CDATA[ */

    var price=[];
    var shipping=[];
    var total=price+shipping;

    function calculateShipping(){
    if (price <= 25){
    shipping = (price + 1.5);
    }
    else {
    shipping = (price * 10 / 100);
    }


window.alert("The purchase price with shipping is "
            + document.calculate.ent.value);
}
/* ]]> */
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name ="calculate" action="" >
<p>Enter Purchase Price</p>
<input type="text" name="ent" >
<input type="button" name="button" value="Submit" onClick="calculateShipping()" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This looks like homework ...

Comment: @Pointy Noooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is obviously homework, so I will put you on the right track.

There are a couple problems with the code:

1. The line `var total=price+shipping;` happens before you actually calculate the shipping
2. Instead of `document.calculate.ent.value` you actually want to display the value of `total`.
3. You haven't assigned the value the user entered into the textbox to the `price` variable. You might consider simply passing the price as an argument to the  `calculateShipping()` function so it would be `function calculateShipping(price) { ... }`

Comment: Don't forget your [string to number conversion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) and [number back to string (with decimal point)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

Comment: Thanks for response. Yes this is homework but I researched the problem and still couldn't solve it, which is why I am asking here. What do you mean by number 2, how do I display the value of total?

Comment: I made changes and now I am getting "undefined." This is very frustrating. Could you please provide me with an example?

Comment: Programming is often frustrating.  In the real world people don't give you code just because you declare that you're frustrated.

Comment: I wasn't asking for the code to my problem. I asked for an "example." Two completely different things.

Answer (score 2):

```
Try:


function calculateShipping() {
    var price = parseFloat(document.getElementById('ent').value);
    var total = (price <=25) ? price + 1.5 : 1.1 * price;
    window.alert("The purchase price with shipping is $" + total.toFixed(2));
}
```

You should also add some validation to your input, because if a non-numeric value is entered, it will crash your function.